# How I can find a key anda value with YAML-cpp?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I have this:

```
YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile(ruta);

for (YAML::const_iterator it = doc.begin(); it != doc.end(); ++it) {
       string key= it->first.as<string>();
       string array= it->second.as<string>();
}
```

And I have a problem with `string array= it->second.as<string>();`

when I run the next code, all it is correct,

```
YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile(ruta);

for (YAML::const_iterator it = doc.begin(); it != doc.end(); ++it) {
      string key= it->first.as<string>();
}
```

but when I run:

```
YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile(ruta)

for (YAML::const_iterator it = doc.begin(); it != doc.end(); ++it) {
      string key= it->first.as<string>();
      string array= it->second.as<string>();
}
```

In the terminal apear this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<int>'
  what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 8, column 8: bad conversion
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

I need help because I do not know why it does not work.I think that the erro it is related to `array = it->second.as<string>();` because if I use  `array = it->second` it work but I need to transform to string.

Answer (score 1):

`yaml-cpp` is reporting that you can't convert the value of your key/value pair into a `std::string`. Do you know what type it should be? Your variable is named `array`, which suggests that you think it's a sequence. If so, you can write:

```
YAML::Node array = it->second;
for (YAML::const_iterator it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); ++it) {
  YAML::Node entry = *it;
  // do something with entry
}
```

Comment: I don not undestand:      for (YAML::Node entry : array) {
  // do something with entry
}

Comment: @seny it's a ranged for loop (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). I replaced it with an iterator loop if you prefer that way.